# MATLAB: Finding the row number of a specific value in a large vector using find function

Tags: matlab, find, signal-processing

I have a struct containing both a matrix `ECoG` and a nested struct `TextMark`.

`ECoG` has 2 columns and many rows (10798910x2 double). The first column represents the values of a signal and the second column represents time.

`TextMark` contains 2 arrays: `times` and `text`. `times` (26x1 double) contains time values which correspond to events represented in `text`, a 26x80 char array.

I am writing a script which finds the index of a specific string in `text` and takes the time value `x` from the same index in `times`.

I want it to then find `x` in the second column of `ECoG` and return the index of the value.

```
x = strmatch('example',output.TextMark.text)
[y] = find(output.ECoG(:,2) == output.TextMark.times(x,:))
```

When I run this, the value returned is

> Empty matrix: 0-by-1

however when I enter the known value of `output.TextMark.times(x,:)`

```
x = strmatch('example',output.TextMark.text)
[y] = find(output.ECoG(:,2) == 1.0219e+03)
```

The value returned is the correct index in `ECoG`.

Given that `output.Textmark.times(x,:) = 1.0219e+03` I don't know why the first command is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I presume the problem results from comparing two `double` elements.
The following code line compares two elements of class double:
`output.ECoG(:,2) == output.TextMark.times(x,:)`
The problem description is a bit confusing (much text, and few values), so I am apologize if I didn't understand you correctly...

Comparing two double elements using `==`, might return false, event when the two elements looks the same when printing them.

Example:

```
a = 1 + 1e-10;
b = 1 + 1e-11;
```

When you display a and b you in Matlab command windows get:

```
    a =

     1.0000

b =

     1.0000
```

But when you type `a == b`, you get:

```
ans =

     0
```

There are many cases when two double elements that supposed to be equal, are not equal.
Refer here http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html for more information about double Floating-Point Numbers in Matalb.
You can read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point as well.

For comparing two double elements you can use the following example:

> abs(testValue - comparisonValue) <= eps(comparisonValue)

I took example from here: https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=double%20precision%20matlab

Another possible solution (applies your code sample):

```
my_eps = 1e-6;  %Set my_eps to small value that difference of two time elements are considered equal.
[y] = find(abs(output.ECoG(:,2) - output.TextMark.times(x,:)) < my_eps)
```